# Trivial answer converted to comment

Tags: support, specific-question

> The OS: FreeBSD does not use block devices. [See] [Low-level disk access in FreeBSD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89887/low-level-disk-access-in-freebsd)

[Is a device being a block or character device determined purely by hardware?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473230/is-a-device-being-a-block-or-character-device-determined-purely-by-hardware#comment864348_473230)

Comments are ephemeral.  I want to write an answer.  Suggestions how I can do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write an answer, then flesh it out a little. What you are showing here is indeed a comment. A simple way to do it would be to quote the more relevant parts of the link in your answer itself. That will both make the answer more useful and will ensure it doesn't become useless even if the link breaks.